# Drupal: where to find the image style applied to on an image field? Efficiently find the URL of styled images?

Tags: image, drupal

This question has two parts.

First, I need to find the url of a set of styled images. I am able to find the URI of these images from a Druapl table. In order to get the URL of a styled image, I can use Drupal's image_style_url(style, uri). Which drupal table stores the information of the correspondence between image fields and styles?

Also I need to find these URLs efficient. Any other way than single call to image_style_url(style, uri) for each image? Can I do a database query to get the URLs (close values) instead of many calls to image_style_url(style, uri). I believe each call to image_style_url generates a database query and it is costly to do so.

I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks for any input!!!

Cheers.

Comment: I'd personally always use the API functions above some queries to a database. Especially with bigger systems. If a next version comes out, the API functions are likely to be the same, but the database structure can be different, breaking the whole thing. And considering the amount of queries Drupal sends, a few more won't be much of a problem. (Caching might reduce this as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the style used for the image formatter in the instance settings for the field, which you can get like this:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_some_field';
$bundle = 'page'; // for example

$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

// Get the image style for a teaser display
$teaser_style = $info['display']['teaser']['settings']['image_style'];
```

I'll leave it to your judgement as to whether this is efficient enough, but the settings are stored in a serialised PHP string in the db table anyway so you're not going to be able to do a clean select which ever way you look at it. I'd be very surprised if there was a shorter way to do this than the above code.

Comment: Thanks so much for this info. It is exactly what I want. One more thing, your solution works for a normal node type. In my case, the image field belong to a taxonomy. I tried the following and it did not work:

`$entity_type = 'taxonomy';`
`$field_name = 'field_my_image';`
`$bundle = 'community';`
`$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);`
`debug($info);`

I got NULL in debug.

Comment: Taxonomy terms are a bit different, the entity type would be `taxonomy_term` and the bundle would be the same...Bundles haven't been implemented as such with taxonomy terms as vocabs are entities in the own right and it wouldn't quite make sense